# ASP.NET MVC - Form Post always redirect when I just want to bind json result to a div

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I'm having a little problem with json result. I'm submitting a contact form, and after the submission, I just want to return some json data (indicating either a success or failed and displays a message) back to the view, without causing a redirect, but it kept redirecting me to the action, here are the codes:

**HTML**

```
<div id="contactForm2" class="grid_6">
        <div id="contactFormContainer">
            @using (Html.BeginForm(MVC.Home.ActionNames.ContactForm, MVC.Home.Name, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "contactForm" }))
            {
                <p>
                    <input type="text" tabindex="1" size="22" value="" id="contactName" class="text_input required"
                        name="contactName" />
                    <label for="contactName">
                        <strong class="leftSpace">Your Name (required)</strong></label></p>
                <p>
                    <input type="text" tabindex="2" size="22" value="" id="contactEmail" class="text_input required"
                        name="contactEmail" />
                    <label for="contactEmail">
                        <strong class="leftSpace">Email (required)</strong></label></p>
                <p>
                    <input type="text" tabindex="2" size="22" value="" id="contactPhone" class="text_input"
                        name="contactPhone" />
                    <label for="contactPhone">
                        <strong class="leftSpace">Phone</strong></label></p>
                <p>
                    <label>
                        <strong class="leftSpace n">Message (required)</strong></label>
                    <textarea tabindex="4" rows="4" cols="56" id="contactMessage" class="text_area required"
                        name="contactMessage"></textarea></p>
                <p>
                    <input type="submit" value="Send" tabindex="5" id="contactSubmit" class="button submit"
                        name="contactSubmit" /></p>
            }
        </div>
        <div id="contactFormStatus">
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
        public virtual JsonResult ContactForm(FormCollection formCollection)
        {
            var name = formCollection["contactName"];
            var email = formCollection["contactEmail"];
            var phone = formCollection["contactPhone"];
            var message = formCollection["contactMessage"];

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(email) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
            {
                return Json(new { success = false, message = "Please complete all the required fields so that I can get back to you. Thanks." });
            }

            // Insert contact form data here...

            return Json(new { success = true, message = "Your inquery has been sent. Thank you." });
        }
```

**javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#contactSubmit').live('click', function () {
        var form = $('#contactForm');
        var formData = form.serialize();

        $.post('/Home/ContactForm',
        formData,
        function (result) {
            var status = $('#contactFormStatus');
            if (result.success) {
                $('#contactForm')[0].reset;
            }
            status.append(result.message);
        },
        'json'
        );
        return false;
    });
});
```

**I've also tried this javascript, but also got a redirect**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#contactSubmit').live('click', function () {
        var form = $('#contactForm');
        var formData = form.serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Home/ContactForm',
            data: formData,
            success: function (result) {
                SubmitContactResult(result);
            },
            cache: false
        });
    });

    function SubmitContactResult(result) {
        var status = $('#contactFormStatus');

        if (result.success) {
            $('#contactForm')[0].reset;
        }

        status.append(result.message);
    }
});
```

Any idea what's going on with my code?

Thank you very much.

Comment: any chance you can get a public version?  I'd be curious to know the http response codes for the post.

Comment: Heartily recommend using either the Google Chrome developer tools or Firebug to debug this kind of thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many things going on with your code and I will try to cover most of them.

The fact that you are getting a redirect means that you have an error somewhere in your javascript. I would start by the following simplification of your code. Personally I prefer subscribing to the `submit` event of the form instead of the `click` event of a submit button:

```
$(function() {
    $('#contactForm').submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: this.method,
            url: this.action,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.success) {
                    $('#contactForm')[0].reset();
                }
                $('#contactFormStatus').text(result.message);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Also notice that you probably want:

```
$('#contactForm')[0].reset();
```

instead of:

```
$('#contactForm')[0].reset;
```

Another thing I've noticed is that you probably want:

```
$('#contactFormStatus').text(result.message);
```

instead of:

```
$('#contactFormStatus').append(result.message);
```

because `result.message` is a plain string returned by your controller, it doesn't represent any DOM element which is what the [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) function expects.

There might also be other errors. My eyes are tired. Use [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/), it will tell you all the errors you've got in your scripts and once you've fixed them all it's gonna work.

---

UPDATE:

I forgot to mention that because what you have is a common scenario (AJAXifying a form) people have written a [jquery plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) for it so that you don't have to go through all the pain over and over again and so that you simply could have:

```
$(function() {
    $('#contactForm').ajaxForm(function(result) {
        if (result.success) {
            $('#contactForm')[0].reset();
        }
        $('#contactFormStatus').text(result.message);
    });
});
```

Now that's much better, isn't it?

Also your controller action looks messy with all those magic strings. How about using a view model:

```
public class ContactViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string ContactName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ContactEmail { get; set; }

    public string ContactPhone { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ContactMessage { get; set; }
}
```

and then simply:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ContactForm(ContactViewModel contact)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Json(new { 
            success = false, 
            message = "Please complete all the required fields so that I can get back to you. Thanks." 
        });
    }

    // Insert contact form data here...
    return Json(new { 
        success = true, 
        message = "Your inquery has been sent. Thank you." 
    });
}
```

Now we've got something much cleaner.

And all that's left is to clean your view by taking advantage of the view model and strongly typed helpers:

```
<div id="contactForm2" class="grid_6">
    <div id="contactFormContainer">
        @using (Html.BeginForm(MVC.Home.ActionNames.ContactForm, MVC.Home.Name, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "contactForm" })) {
            <p>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ContactName, new { tabindex = "1", size = "22", @class = "text_input required" })
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ContactName, "Your Name (required)")
            </p>
            <p>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ContactEmail, new { tabindex = "2", size = "22", @class = "text_input required" })
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ContactEmail, "Email (required)")
            </p>
            <p>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ContactPhone, new { tabindex = "3", size = "22", @class = "text_input" })
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ContactPhone, "Phone")
            </p>
            <p>
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ContactMessage, "Message (required)")
                @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.ContactMessage, 4, 56, new { tabindex = "4", @class = "text_input required" })
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Send" tabindex="5" id="contactSubmit" class="button submit" name="contactSubmit" />
            </p>
        }
    </div>
    <div id="contactFormStatus">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Darin, perfect! Your solution is so clean and works nicely. Thank you very much.

Comment: nice :) Although I don't know if it works but I know this is a great help. I will vote for the effort and a much detailed and clear response.

Comment: Bit late, but what a great reply. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Ive done it the following way with $.post()

```
$('#contactForm').live('submit', function () {
//rest of code
});
```